# date filter that adjusts for Daylight Saving

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a date (in UTC milliseconds) that I am displaying on a page (AngularJS 1.4.0), and the users would like to see it in Eastern time, regardless of the time zone set on their computer.

I am using the **date** filter, and from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) I see

> `$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)`
>
> Timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset, for example, `'+0430'` (4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

Using timestamps from today, if I use something like

`{{ record.Timestamp | date:'HH:mm:ss.sss':'EST' }}`

it writes the time as I expect, but I think I'm going to be off by an hour when DST rolls around.  I can also specify `'EDT'` and it will bump the time ahead an hour, but is there a timezone abbreviation I could use that just means "Eastern", and uses the date itself to determine whether to use EST or EDT? Or am I going to need to inspect the date and create an offset myself: either -0500/EST or -0400/EDT, depending on the date? (and it looks like `timezone` can only be a string, not a function, so that's going to complicate my auto-detection).

It just seems unlikely that anyone would want to hard-code the display to either EST or EDT - it's much more likely that they want the time zone, adjusted for DST.

Comment: The problem is that Daylight Saving Time is not observed universally. Otherwise, you could check `getTimezoneOffset()` from a Date in January and again in July and compare the current Date's offset, then use `EDT` or `EST` appropriately. But if the code would run in, say, Arizona or Hawaii, that wouldn't work.

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with my possible workaround than the original problem, right?  I probably would be attempting something like that to determine DST, and right now we wouldn't have any users in those areas, but _never say never_...

Comment: Depends on what you think of as your "original problem" :). To me, the real problem is the date filter's use of US time zone abbreviations instead of the somewhat more standard [IANA list](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html), which don't specify DST. I do agree with Yaser's answer regarding MomentJS.

Comment: Ha! I was just trying out the America/New_York and others from that list, since I see that they *do* work on `Date.toLocaleString`, but no luck. I was hoping there was a timezone string for the built-in filter that I was just overlooking, but it appears not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) for this kind of stuff to get the right datetime. Filter in AngularJS is just to format the datetime object and show it in UI.

You can also use some ready to use directives like [Angular-Moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment).
It has got all sort of filtering available.

Comment: Well, I *am* just trying to format the datetime for display in the UI - this is purely presentational. I'll look into `momentjs`, but I'm reluctant to add another couple of libraries for just that piece. The `timezone` addition to the Angular date filter was great - I could now show it in UTC! - but it seems just a little lacking for actual time zones.

Comment: momentjs has been around for a while and it has some great features. You are right about adding another lib but I wouldn't consider this as a big issue, I've used moment in a couple of projects and it works perfect

Comment: I resisted but with DST fast approaching I've put in angular-moment.js and it seems to be working well.